# django 3.2 how to loop a field with foreign-keys

Tags: python, django

I'd like to loop a field based from the Question Model. Here are my models.## Heading ##

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.deletion import CASCADE
from django.conf import settings
class Question(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    question = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
class Declaration(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='declarations', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
class Checklist(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    declaration = models.ForeignKey(Declaration, related_name='checklist_declaration', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, related_name='checklist_question', on_delete=models.CASCADE, limit_choices_to={'is_active': 'True'})
    is_yes = models.BooleanField()
```

and my forms.py

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django import forms
from declaration.models import Checklist, Question

class DeclarationForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Declaration
    fields = '__all__'
class ChecklistForm(forms.ModelForm):
    is_yes = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Checklist
        fields = ['question', 'is_yes']
```

and here is my expected output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxuYe.png)

I dunno how to do it in the forms.py since django's only way to validate fields is through forms.

*Additional question
this is my views.

```
def submit(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    checklist = ChecklistForm(request.POST)
    declaration = DeclarationForm(request.POST)
    if declaration.is_valid() and checklist.is_valid():
        user = request.user
        declaration = Declaration.objects.create(user=user)
        declaration.save()
        checklist.save(commit=False)
        checklist.declaration = declaration
        checklist.save()

        return redirect('student-dashboard')
```

do i need to loop to check every checklist to work? it only saves declaration object but no checklists objects and shows no error.

Updated***

Following the approach of TaipanRex it works but my problem is it looks like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMQOK.png)

Is there a way to instead of show dropdown menu of the question just the quest text instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to need two Forms, a `DeclarationForm` and a `ChecklistForm` (though I would probably rename your Checklist model to DeclarationQuestionAnswer). Remove the `__init__` code from your ChecklistForm and add all the fields to `fields`.

You are going to use [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/formsets/) to list all the questions in your form. You will have to check out the docs on how these work, but to set the formset up you will do this:

```
questions = []
for q in Question.objects.all():
    questions.append({'question': str(q.id), 'is_yes': None})
formset = inlineformset_factory(Declaration, Checklist,
    form=ChecklistForm, fk_name="declaration", extra=len(questions),
                can_delete=False)
question_formset = formset(prefix='questions_fs', initial=questions)
```

UPDATED: Your view for saving the forms is not correct, should be something like this:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    formset = inlineformset_factory(Declaration, Checklist,
    form=ChecklistForm, fk_name="declaration")
    declaration_form = DeclarationForm(request.POST)
    if declaration_form.is_valid():
        declaration_form.user = request.user
        declaration = declaration_form.save(commit=False)
        checklist = formset(request.POST, prefix='question_fs', instance=declaration)
    if checklist.is_valid():
            with transaction.atomic():
                declaration.save()
                checklist.save()
```

Comment: Hi, i tried this approach and it did worked as expected on it is not in radioselect format. is there a way to convert it to radioselect so it will look like whats on the image? thanks so much and i really appreciate your feedback and time.

Comment: `widget=forms.RadioSelect()` is not correct, change it to `widget=forms.RadioSelect`

Comment: hi is my views correct?
def submit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        checklist = ChecklistForm(request.POST)
        declaration = DeclarationForm(request.POST)
        if declaration.is_valid() and checklist.is_valid():
            user = request.user
            declaration = Declaration.objects.create(user=user)
            declaration.save()
            for q in Q
            checklist.save(commit=False)
            checklist.declaration = declaration
            checklist.save()

            return redirect('student-dashboard')

Comment: i updated my question above added my views but i implemented your solution and it works only it doesnt save the checklist model just declaration model. since it is a multiple checklist entry per 1 declaration model.

Comment: your solution is working only that declaration.is_valid() is not passing through something is missing i guess.

Comment: i think the error is here

views.py", line 67, in submit
    checklist = formset(request.POST, prefix='question_fs', instance=declaration)

AttributeError: 'DeclarationForm' object has no attribute 'pk'

Comment: Yeah sorry, should use `declaration_form` as variable name for the form, then use `declaration` as variable name for what is returned from `.save(commit=False)`. Updated the answer again.

Comment: thanks mate the error is gone now but the checkist.is_valid(() is returning false :(

Comment: i think there is something wrong with the code, it cannot pass the checklist.is_valid()

Comment: then you need to check what the validation error is. `print(checklist.errors)`

Comment: hi mate checklist is ok but declaration_form is not passing the current user since declaration form only contains 1 field the foreignkey user_id

Answer (score 0):

Hi tenzai and welcome to the great stackoverflow community!

### 1. django model.ManyToManyField

One way to deal with such many to many architecture (Checklist) is the use django admin widget with the `models.ManyToManyField` declaration. Widget in `forms.py` `from django.contrib.admin.widgets import FilteredSelectMultiple`. But for that, you'll have to simplify your model.

1. `Checklist.is_yes` field is useless since data presence in the checklist table attest that a user checked a question.
2. If you don't have any other field in `Declaration` class it is also useless.

From there, the only thing you need is the declaration of a many2many relation to `Question` class from `User` class. But in that case, you'll have to use a [custom user model](https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-custom-user-model) or a `one to one` relation to `Auth.models.User` class of django. Cfr. [How to Extend Django User Model](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html)

```py
# Add this question field to the custom User class
question = models.ManyToManyField(Question, verbose_name="Question")
```

The form become

```py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import FilteredSelectMultiple

class ChecklistForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        widgets = {"question" : 
             FilteredSelectMultiple(Question._meta.verbose_name_plural, False)
        }
```

But this will result in a simple drag and drop of your questions from left to right.

### 2. Left join raw SQL

One other way to do it would be to build a function view with a left join raw SQL. Keep your model as it is

##### 2.1. models.py

Remarks from point 1. remains and therefore `Checklist` class become

```py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

my_user_model = get_user_model()

class Checklist(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(my_user_model, related_name='checklist_declaration', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, related_name='checklist_question', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

You must go for this architecture if you are planing to add specific fields into the Checklist (Question & User combinations)

##### 2.2. views.py

Note for `Checklist.is_deletable` method called into the view:

> If your selected fields of questions are referenced somewhere in your
> DB you need to ensure that the unselection of the choice will not
> delete all related field of the specified user quesion in your DB.
> That's where the
> [is_deletable](https://gist.github.com/freewayz/69d1b8bcb3c225bea57bd70ee1e765f8)
> method intervenes.

```py
import logging

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .models import Checklist, Question

LOG = logging.getLogger(__name__)

@login_required
def my_question(request):
    """
    Function view based on raw select in order to manage outer join
    and display
    """
    myuser = request.user
    qchecks = Checklist.objects.raw('''
    select qq.id, qq.title, aa.qid from question_question as qq
    left join (select question_id as qid
                 from question_checklist
                where user_id = {0}) aa
    on aa.qid = qq.id
    order by qq.title ASC
    '''.format(myuser.id))

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # selected elements provided by the form
        selected = request.POST.getlist("qcheck")
        for ticked in selected:
            ticked_inst = Question.objects.get(id=ticked)
            Checklist.objects.for_user(myuser).get_or_create(profile=myuser,
                                                             question=ticked_inst)

        # Get unselected elements and remove them
        unselected_inst = Question.objects.exclude(id__in=selected)
        for unticked in unselected_inst:
            try:
                obj = Checklist.objects.filter(user=myuser).get(question=unticked)
                # check related before delete
                related_list = Checklist.is_deletable(obj)
                if related_list:
                    messages.error(request,
                        _(f"Checklist delete {obj}. Please first delete related records.")
                    )
                    for related in related_list:
                        related_model = related.model._meta.verbose_name
                        related_values = [i.__str__() for i in related.all()]
                        msg = f"{related_model}: {related_values}"
                        messages.warning(request, msg)
                    return redirect('my_question')
                else:
                    obj.delete()
            except Checklist.DoesNotExist:
                pass
        messages.success(request, _('Changes saved'),
                                fail_silently=True)
        
        return redirect('my_question')

    context = {'user': request.user,
               'qchecks': qchecks,
               'myuser': myuser,
               'upd_allowed': upd_allowed}

    return render(request, 'select_question_form.html', context)
```

##### 2.3. html template (select_question_form.html)

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block content %}

<h2>Do you have</h2>

{% if qchecks %}
    <table class="table">
        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for qcheck in qchecks %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ qcheck.title }}</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="qcheck" value="{{ qcheck.id }}" {% if qcheck.id == qcheck.qid %} checked {% endif %}
                    {% if not upd_allowed%} disabled{% endif %}/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        {% if upd_allowed %}
        <tr><td colspan="2"><input class="btn btn-danger2" type="submit" value="{% trans "Save" %}" /></td></tr>
        {% endif %}
        
        </form>
    </table>
{% else %}
    <p>No question check.</p>
{% endif %}

{% endblock content %}
```

##### 2.4 urls.py

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('questions', views.my_question, name='my_question')
]
```

Comment: Thanks mate for your feedback. The purpose of the Declaration model is to group them according to the user and their checklists. Meaning the user can submit the form every day as a requirement before entering class for contact tracing purposes in this time of pandemic.

Comment: also i agree with this "Checklist.is_yes field is useless since data presence in the checklist table attest that a user checked a question." since it can save data storage on my db too. i can reimplement it but the Declaration model is like a pivot table? the purpose of that is_yes field is to makesure they dont skip every single question in the form which is yes or no. if checkbox is the approach they might accidentally ignore some questions.